# RuntimeBinderException on dynamic Linq with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: dynamic, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook C# SDK in a canvas app.

When running this code...

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFansIds(string pageId, IEnumerable<string> userIds)
{
    if (userIds.Count() == 0)
        return new List<string>();

    var fb = new FacebookApp();
    string query = String.Format("select uid from page_fan where uid IN ( {0} ) and page_id = {1}",
        String.Join(",", userIds),
        pageId
    );
    dynamic result = fb.Fql(query);
    return result.Select((Func<dynamic, string>)(x => x.uid)).ToList();
}
```

I get the following Exception:

```
RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

The code does the following:

- It performs a FQL query to get an `JsonArray` contaning `JsonObject` each with a uid Property (containing the uids of the users that are not fan of some fanpage.
- The Select just converts all the dynamic objects into a `List<string>`

The FQL part just works correctly as i can see the results in the debugger.
The problem is with the `Select` that I can't make it work.

How can I fix the dynamic lambda ??? (Please don't just tell me to use a foreach, which is what I am currently doing right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that extension methods cannot be used on dynamic objects. Cast the result of the query to a JsonArray and then you can use linq expressions on the JsonArray.

```
var result = (JsonArray)fb.Fql(query);
return result.Select((Func<dynamic, string>)(x => x.uid)).ToList();
```